# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character. Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I created parametrized Linked Service that accepts URL as AccountKey as parameters.

```
{
    "name": "MyLinkedService",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlobFS",
        "parameters": {
            "URL": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "accountkey": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "@{linkedService().URL}",
            "accountkey": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "**********"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

"Test connection" works fine.

[image]

However, when I execute pipeline it gives me an error saying that account key in Linked Service is invalid:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters
azure data factory
```

[image]

I understand that account key contains symbols, but that is how my account key looks like.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and dot same result when My account key contains special characters.

> **Base64 only contains A–Z , a–z , 0–9 , + , / and = .**

**To resolve the issue, make sure you are using correct Account key of ADLS.**

Form here you can copy the Account Key and paste it there.

[image]

**My connection:**

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by saying you got "same result"? You mean you getting an error if your account key contains special characters?

Comment: and yes, that is the place I get my key account key. They both contain special characters

Comment: Yes when I tried with the account key and added special characters in it. Got same error.

Comment: Make sure it doesn't contain additional spaces while copying it.

Comment: So here is an update. If I recreate Linked Service and enter credentials - it works fine. Next day, I will try to execute pipeline - and it gives me the base 64 error. Several times I tried already and always problem on next day. Why is that?

Comment: basically, checking connection on a Linked Service and DataSet seperately - getting "Connection Successful". But executing Copy Activity - gives me an error